# In a stored procedure how to skip to next query statement even if the previous statement fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm hoping someone can give me an idea on how to handle this situation. I have a stored procedure that updates various tables. Some queries require connecting to different linked servers. Sometimes those linked servers are down and i need the procedure to still run the next statements regardless. Below is an example:

```
--Stored Procedure
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table1
        SELECT *
        FROM Z1;

    -- IF ABOVE FAILS GO TO NEXT QUERY ANYWAY
    INSERT INTO table1
        SELECT *
        FROM Z2;

    -- IF ABOVE FAILS GO TO NEXT QUERY ANYWAY
    INSERT INTO table1
        SELECT *
        FROM Z3;
END
```

Comment: What does "FAIL" mean?

Comment: by fail like in my case if it cant connect to the server so i get back in error message

Comment: @KatherinePacheco - Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do what you want with `TRY`/`CATCH` blocks:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM Z1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- you can do something here if you want
    END CATCH;

    -- IF ABOVE FAILS GO TO NEXT QUERY ANYWAY

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM Z2;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- you can do something here if you want
    END CATCH;

    -- IF ABOVE FAILS GO TO NEXT QUERY ANYWAY

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM Z3;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- you can do something here if you want
    END CATCH;
END;
```

This handles *runtime* errors.  If you have *compile* time errors -- such as tables not existing or the columns not matching between the tables, then this doesn't help.

Comment: this seem like a good solution. I think it might work ill test and let you know thank you Gordon

Answer (score 0):

If this were run from say ssms as a bunch of ordinary queries, I would've put batch separators between each of them to treat them separately. However since this is a stored procedure you can't do that. One way to get around that could be to make one stored procedure of each query and put all of them as steps inside a SQL Server Agent job. You run the job and each step runs in order from top to bottom even if some in the middle fail.

Answer (score 0):

even this will also work: @@ROWCOUNT is oracle's equivalent of sql%rowcount

```
--Stored Procedure
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table1
        SELECT *
        FROM Z1;


    IF @@ROWCOUNT <>1 
    INSERT INTO table1
        SELECT *
        FROM Z2;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <>1 
    INSERT INTO table1
        SELECT *
        FROM Z3;
END
```